# Ridge Detection for Retinopathy of Prematurity Fundus Images using OpenCV and Python

Tags: opencv

[image]

Hi. I am trying to find the demarcation line / ridge from the fundus images that you see in the middle separating the retina. This demarcation / ridge line appears between the normal and abnormal vessels in babies with Retinopathy of prematurity. I tried to use the RidgeDetection code in OpenCV but these identify all the ridges. I only want to extract the line that you see in the middle of the image

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
f.add_subplot(4,3,5)
plt.imshow(gray, cmap = 'gray')

# Identifying the Ridge
ridge_filter = cv2.ximgproc.RidgeDetectionFilter_create()
ridges = ridge_filter.getRidgeFilteredImage(img)
```

In another blog someone mentioned about

```
from skimage.features import hessian_matrix, hessian_matrix_eigvals
def detect_ridges(gray, sigma=3.0):
    hxx, hyy, hxy = hessian_matrix(gray, sigma)
    i1, i2 = hessian_matrix_eigvals(hxx, hxy, hyy)
    return i1, i2
```

However this too does not work. Can you please suggest the code and approach?

Comment: The ridge you are interested in is lighter than its surroundings. You can use this information to filter it from all other ridges detected by your filter.

Comment: Dhanushka: with ridge_filter.getRidgeFilteredImage it shows all the veins including  the demarcation line. What function should I use next to filter all the veins

Comment: May be you can threshold these **vein pixels** using Otsu's method, or cluster them into two using `kmeans`.

Answer (score 0):

Very cool area of investigation. It appears that the ML is overtrained. You might get lucky and drop on the correct combination, but you'll never really know whether it is robust against an entire population.

This will sound boring BUT is there any change you can obtain a large number of validated data set of images with retinopathy and an equal number of healthy babies? I would pursue a supervised learning approach to establish a new decision boundary. In that case its a straight implementation of SciKit-learn.

I assume "ridge" here is meant in a technical sense  and doesn't relate to ridge analysis.

Comment: I am not wanting to use ML right now. Only image processing. I see

Comment: The point is that a ML approach will establish the boundary you want and its advantage (over guessing) is that it will allow/tolerate more variation between individual babies.

Comment: Michael thanks. any suggestion on what the code should look like

Comment: Hi, this is another question. I would use SciKit Learn (deep learning module for Python) and use "Linear" "Ridge" "Lasso"  regression. HOWEVER I don't work with images. One approach used with images is non-negative factorisation (PCA on pixels), albeit this is for unsupervised learning (which isn't quite what you want). Thus there's not much point in supplying code to you because I don't know the techniques that will convert the pixels into meaningful statistical information, after that I'm good.